# How do I change url with tabbed content?

Tags: javascript, url, tabs

I am using tabs to organize the content on my page. I am worried about SEO friendliness with this method so I think what would help is to have a unique url for each tab. When I click these tabs currently, the url stays the same. The tabbing script is in javascript, which I am quite novice in. If I had a downloaded js file that does all of this for me, is there a simple function I can add to the end of this file that will add a new hash at the end of my url when I click on any tab so that search engines will be able to go to this tab specifically when searched. This may not even be a viable solution to my problem, I don't know.

I imagine some of the veterans on this site will rip this question apart for vagueness/lack of supporting code to help you help me out. This is my first post, be gentle. Thanks.

Comment: `A hash function is any well-defined procedure or mathematical function that converts a large amount of data into a small datum, usually a single integer.`    -Tag

Comment: @Dude what does that have to do with a url hash? ie `window.location.hash` . More than one definition for `hash` ...including several different human consumable varieties

Comment: @charlietfl Nothing. Yes. Not related to the tag, which had a definition.